# Understanding STM8 pipelining

Tags: opcode, instruction-set, benchmarking, cpu-cycles, stm8

I’m trying to understand STM8 pipelining to be able to predict how much cycles my code will need.

I have this example, where I toggle a GPIO pin for 4 cycles each.
Iff `loop` is aligned at 4byte-boundary + 3, the pin stays active for 5 cycles (i.e. one more than it should). I wonder why?

```
// Switches port D2, 5 cycles high, 4 cycles low
void main(void)
{
    __asm
        bset 0x5011, #2 ; output mode
        bset 0x5012, #2 ; push-pull
        bset 0x5013, #2 ; fast switching

        jra _loop
    .bndry 4
        nop
        nop
        nop
    _loop:
        nop
        bset 0x500f, #2
        nop
        nop
        nop
        bres 0x500f, #2
        jra _loop
    __endasm;
}
```

A bit more context:

- `bset`/`bres` are 4 byte instructions, `nop` 1 byte.
- The `nop`/`bset`/`bres` instructions take 1 cycle each.
- The `jra` instruction takes two cycles. I think in the first cycle, the instruction cache is filled with the next 32bit value, i.e. in this case the `nop` instruction only. And the 2nd cycle is actually just the CPU being stalled while decoding the next instruction.

So in cycles:

1. `bres` clears the pin
2. `jra`, pipeline flush, `nop` fetch
3. `nop` decode, `bset` fetch
4. `nop` execute, `bset` decode, next `nop` fetch
5. `bset` execute sets the pin
6. `nop`, `bres` fetch
7. `nop`
8. `nop`, `bres` decode
9. `bres` execute clears the pin

According to this, the pin should stay LOW for 4 cycles and HIGH for 4 cycles, but it’s staying HIGH for 5 cycles.

In any other alignment case, the pin is LOW/HIGH for 4 cycles as expected.

I think, if the PIN stays high for an extra cycle that must mean that the execution pipeline is stalled after the `bset` instruction (the `nop`s thereafter provide enough time to make sure that `bres` later is ready to execute immediately). But according to my understanding `nop` (for 6.) would already be fetched in 4.

Any idea how this behavior can be explained? I couldn’t find any hints in the [manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/43/24/13/9a/89/df/45/ed/CD00161709.pdf/files/CD00161709.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161709.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in section 5.4, which basically says that throughout the [programming manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/43/24/13/9a/89/df/45/ed/CD00161709.pdf/files/CD00161709.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161709.pdf), "a simplified convention providing a good match with reality" will be used. From my experience, this simplified convention is indeed a good approximate for a longer sequence, but unusable for exact per-instruction timing, even if you're working on assembly level and control alignment. Take "SLA addr" as an example. It is documented to use 1 cycle. Put three of them in sequence to implement the C equivalent of "*(addr) << 3", and you'll clock up 5-6 cycles.

Actual cycles used for decoding and execution are undocumented. Apart from the obvious reasons, there is no comprehensive documentation about what causes pipeline stalls. I was able to get some insight into this by configuring TIM2 with a prescaler of /1 and reload values of 0xFFFF while using ST-LINK/V2 to step through my code. You can then keep a watch on TIM2_CNTRL to see cycles consumed (== the aggregate value of executing the previous and decoding the current instruction).

Things to keep an eye on are obviously instructions spanning 32-bit boundaries. There were also cases where loading instructions from the next 32-bit word caused an unexpected additional cycle in a sequence of NOPs, suggesting that any fetch (even if not necessary for the current or next instruction) costs 1 cycle? I've seen CALLs to targets aligned to 32 bit boundaries taking 4-7 cycles, suggesting that the CPU was still busy executing the previous instruction or stalling the call for unknown reason. Modifying the SP (push/pop or direct add/sub) seems to be causing stalls under certain conditions.

Any additional insight appreciated!